# Can I use testng groups read from a file?

Tags: java, testng

I tried using testng groups read from external file. It is giving a compile time error stating that it can only take string constants. It looks like below:

```
@Test(dataProvider="myData", DataProviderClass=MyDataProvider.class, groups=MyGroups.getGroups())
public void test()
{
 //...
}
```

I cannot do the above with TestNG as of now. So is there way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try building an implementation around `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` interface that TestNG provides to you as a listener, and within its `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer#transform` method you can inject the group information dynamically. Your `transform()` implementation could be enriched such that it reads the group information from an external data source. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to set a group with this transformer to a testng method which is not selected for run and also include the method for run.

Comment: Nope. I doubt if that can be done. Groups are basically method selectors but to what set of TestNG methods should it be applied is determined by either `<packages>` tag (or) `<classes>` tag. So if a particular method is not even picked up to be included in the set, then a method selector cannot force it to be included. Hope that makes sense. To get past this, you can perhaps resort to using a very greedy `<packages>` entry.

Comment: I have a listener, which applies group to every test using org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer#transform. I have a testNG xml (sanity.xml) which runs on a complete package and I have mentioned few group names to filter out methods in this xml. 
My question is that how can we run IAnnotationTransformer#transform method to the complete package before starting sanity.xml execution so that sanity.xml will be able to know which test cases to filter from complete package on group names?

Comment: I would suggest you to please open a new question